# finding css load in joomla 2.5 rockettheme template

Tags: css, joomla, load

I am trying to unload some css files of my template that created by rocket theme for joomla2.5 , but I can't find the place of loading css files , I was looking in gantry folder but I can't find any solution , do you know template where loads css file? I mean  , I already searched all php files of gantry and template and didn't find anything

Comment: Are you looking for the page that loads the stylesheets? Have you tried doing something as simple as a project-wide search for `.css`? It's hard to answer a "file-base" question without have access to it. :|

Comment: This sounds like you are asking others to teach you basic functionality.  Show/discuss what you have done.  Demonstrate that you have tried to solve it on your own first.  Then, come for help.

Comment: CSS files can literally be included from any PHP file (though it is more common in some than others). Either way, there is no single file that you can find. Do a file search on the file that you want to stop from loading.

Comment: guys! believe me , I already searching all the files , but I didn't find anything , if you know where it is tell me otherwise please don't send spam!

Answer (score 0):

CSS files in Joomla are stored in the directory for the template being used. The directory is usually called CSS and the CSS files in it have .css extensions.

You might want to take another approach than what you asked for. Make a copy of the CSS files being used with the Joomla Template. Then go in there and take out most or all of the unwanted CSS. This way, you aren't digging around in the core files and modifying the template itself.

Comment: yes you are right , but i need to disable loading some css files , how can i find the line that recall that file and remove it?

Comment: your mean is : I can delete css file from css folder and then they will not load?

Answer (score 0):

RocketTheme Gantry templates use LESS which is compiled into CSS.

You can find the LESS files in the /templates/[TEMPLATE-NAME]/less/ folder.

Rather than editing these file directly, it is better to override the settings using a custom LESS file or custom CSS file that Gantry allows for.

A custom LESS file should be created at /templates/[TEMPLATE-NAME]/less/template-custom.less

A custom CSS file should be created at /templates/[TEMPLATE-NAME]/css/[TEMPLATE-NAME]-custom.css

References:

- http://www.rockettheme.com/blog/coding/1767-basics-debugging-a-customizing-with-lesscss
- http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/advanced/less_css.md